Error al momento de exportar a documento un reporte de crystal reports en web
tengo el siguiente error en mi proyecto mvc en c#.net framework al momento que quiero realizar que exporte mi reporte a un documento pdf para mostrarlo en una pagina, este es mi codigo:
public FileStreamResult CrearReporte()
        {
                try
                {
                    var Reporte = new ReportDocument();
                    Reporte.Load(Nombre_reporte);
                //agrega los parametros usados en el reporte
                if (ListaParametros.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x <= ListaParametros.Count - 1; x++)
                        {
                            Reporte.SetParameterValue(ListaParametros[x].NombreParametro,ListaParametros[x].ValorParamentro);
                        }

                    }
                    // Configura las credenciales de la base de datos
                    ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                    connectionInfo.ServerName = this.Nombre_servidor;
                    connectionInfo.DatabaseName = this.Nombre_db;
                    connectionInfo.UserID = this.Nombre_usuario;
                    connectionInfo.Password = this.Password_servidor;

                    // Obtén la colección de tablas del informe y actualiza las credenciales para cada tabla
                    TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
                    Tables tables = Reporte.Database.Tables;
                    foreach (Table table in tables)
                    {
                        tableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
                        tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
                        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
                    }
                    
                    Stream stream = Reporte.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                return  new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf") ;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw (ex);
                }
        }

el error que me da es este : Error: Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase+FileStreamDeleteOnClose'.
De antemano agradezco su tiempo por ayudarme con mi problema.
